# Using stringbuilder and bufferedreader to read more than one link

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader, stringbuilder, delimiter

I am trying to read more than one rss link from the xml source txt file in the code below. I am using `;` as the delimiter. From debug, it seems to be sending all the links to `RSS_LINK`, which is obviously not going to work.

```
StringBuilder rsslink = new StringBuilder();
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.xmlsource);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line = null;

try {
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
    {
       rsslink.append(line) ;
    }
    String [] arr = rsslink.toString().split(";"); 
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
        }
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String RSS_LINK = rsslink.toString();

Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Service started");
List<RssItem> rssItems = null;
try 
{
    XMLRssParser parser = new XMLRssParser();
    rssItems = parser.parse(getInputStream(RSS_LINK));
} 
catch (XmlPullParserException e) 
{
    Log.w(e.getMessage(), e);
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
    Log.w(e.getMessage(), e);
}
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable(ITEMS, (Serializable) rssItems);
ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(RECEIVER);
receiver.send(0, bundle);
}
```

**New Code**

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) 
{   
    StringBuilder rsslink = new StringBuilder();
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.xmlsource);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line = null;

    try {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
           rsslink.append(line) ;
        }
        String [] arr = rsslink.toString().split(";"); 
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            String RssLink = arr[i];

            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Service started");
            List<RssItem> rssItems = null;
            try 
            {
                XMLRssParser parser = new XMLRssParser();
                rssItems = parser.parse(getInputStream(RssLink));
            } 
            catch (XmlPullParserException e) 
            {
                Log.w(e.getMessage(), e);
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                Log.w(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable(ITEMS, (Serializable) rssItems);
            ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(RECEIVER);
            receiver.send(0, bundle);
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You split the `rsslink`'s but instead of using the resulting `arr` you continue to work with `rsslink` which still has all links and `;` combined.

You need to put all rss handling (parsing etc) into the loop:

```
String [] arr = rsslink.toString().split(";"); 
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        // HERE IS THE PLACE TO HANDLE a single RSS Link. arr contains the single link
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, i got it to somewhat work by moving the handling part into the for loop and then sending `RSS_LINK = arr[i]` The problem im facing now is that it is cycling through the links and getting rid of the previous link when it goes back to the top of the loop, so it only shows the contents of the link that is within the loop.

Comment: Thank you for the new code. It looks like this line: `ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(RECEIVER);` refers always to the same instance of the receiver and the the call to `send(0, bundle)` therefore kind of cancels or overwrites the send in the loop before. But here, my knowledge comes to an end. You can give it a try to make sure you always get a new instance of the receiver - or - you try to wait for the result before you send the next request - or - you ask again in stackoverflow.com for this particular problem. Hope it was at least helpful up to this point :-)

Comment: thank you for your help..i'll choose this as the answer regardless